# Proving $1\times 1! + 2\times 2! + 3\times 3! +\cdots.+n\times n! = (n+1)! -1 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Prove that:
>   $$1\times 1! + 2\times 2! + 3\times 3! +\cdots+n\times n! = (n+1)! -1 $$

My attempt :-

Let

S=
$1\times 1! + 2\times 2! + 3\times 3! + ...+n\times n! = (n+1)! -1 $
= $1\times 1! + 4\times 1! + 9\times 2! + 16\times 3! + ...+ n^2 \times (n-1)!$

Now i wanna relate this sum with the original sum to get it but i do not know how can i do it ?

Comment: You could prove it by mathematical induction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
n(n!) & = (n + 1 - 1)n! \\
& = (n+1)n! - n! \\
& = (n+1)! - n!
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This shows the sum forms a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).